# Can expected drive distance (for an novice) be derived from disc statistics?

Tags: equipment, disc-golf

Innova published [this chart](http://www.innovadiscs.com/media/PDF/2014-chart-driver.pdf) that shows driver distance  is roughly a function of the speed metric in perfect conditions. I own a Cheetah disc (speed 6) but my best throws never come close to the listed 300 feet. At best, my drives are 200 feet. More experienced golfers I play with are able to drive a lot further than me.

So given that I'm not (yet) able to drive perfectly, is speed the best number to look at for guessing my personal maximum distance with a particular disc?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.

You can be sure that you will throw your faster discs further than your putters, but actually the farthest disc will be the disc that is most suitable with your arm speed and technique.

Furthermore in discgolf the distance is not the only thing you should be worried about, very important thing is also accuracy and stability. Usually slower discs have less fade in the end and provide more stable results.

For a novice I recommend throwing something in speed of 6 or 7. Very popular disc is Innova Teebird, it is most used fairway driver and is very stable and accurate. Your Cheetah should be okay also. You should not move to a faster disc until you can throw these disc constantly more than 300-330 feet. You will probably throw these disc as far as any faster disc like speed 11 anyways.

If you start to get more advanced and have more speed in arm, you are able to throw faster discs further, but that will take time and practice.

Check this video out, it will guide you through about which driver you should be using. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvpdTf_FjjM